# Integral involving two hypergeometric functions of multiple variables.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, convolution, hypergeometric-function

Let us define an auxiliary functions:
$$f_i(x)=x^{c_i-1}\Phi^{(2)}_2(b_i,b'_i;c_i;v_i x,w_i x)$$
with $\Phi^{(2)}_2(\cdot)$ - [standard Humbert function of two variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series) and $i=1,2$.

**The question is**: Is it possible to compute the following integral
$$\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}f_1(x)f_2(x-\alpha){\rm d}x.$$
At a first glance it looks like a convolution integral. I can find the Laplace transform of the functions $f_i(x)$ but will this approach be correct since it only *"looks like"* but not a convolution.
The series representation of Humbert functions does not give any solution since the integral blows up.

I know that the integral is finite, since it represents some combination of probability distributions and the numeric solution can be obtained without any problem. What I am seeking is the closed-form solution.

**Addendum**: the parameter $x\geq 0$, but $v_i, w_i$ can be negative.

Comment: To be honest I’ve ran across a similar problem couple months ago, but had no time to cope with it, thus I think it would be helpful to draw some attention to this post.

Comment: Is $\Phi^{(2)}_2$ the second derivative of $\Phi_2$?

Comment: @vitamind No, this is a standard notation for the Humbert function of two variables. Its general form for n variables is $\Phi^{(n)}_2$. In most papers a shorthand notation $\Phi^{(2)}_2=\Phi_2$ is used.

Comment: You want a closed form solution. Is a hypergeometric series by your definition a closed form?

Comment: @vitamind Yes, I full understand that the problem is stated in terms of the hypergeometric series and the solution can be given in terms of the hypergeometric series.

Comment: @math.amuser Can we restrict $c_i$ to be an natural number? Otherwise it's going to be very hard, I think even impossible, to find a closed form. What we could do is maybe replace $c_i$ with $\lfloor c_i \rfloor$, so that the error is minimal.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but if you want your cross-correlation integral to look like a convolution, define:

$$g_2(x) = f_2(-x)H(-x) $$

where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside unit step function.

Then

$$\begin{align*} I(\alpha) &= \int_\alpha^\infty f_1(x)f_2(x-\alpha) dx\\
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_1(x)f_2(x-\alpha)H(x-\alpha) dx\\
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_1(x)g_2(\alpha-x) dx\\
\\
&= (f_1*g_2)(\alpha) \\
\end{align*}$$

is your integral expressed as a convolution.